# Get position of each item in a list

Tags: c#, list

If I am looping through items in a list, how do I get the position of each item (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 if there are 5 items?

```
    public void AllocatePosition(List<DbConnect.BidList> createBidList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < createBidList.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(createBidList[i].ToString()); // show position of item (i.e. is it first, second, third...on the list
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps i am missing the point: i.ToString() ?

Comment: You could do `createBidList.IndexOf(createBidList[i])`, but that seems a bit over the top when *you already have i*.

Comment: Sorry lads - had a blonde moment

Comment: It happens to all of us @methuselah.

Comment: Though I really don't understand the votes to close for the question being unclear.  It seems overly clear, if anything :-).

Comment: Do you mean you want to translate the integer `i` to a string like "first" "second" "third", etc?

Comment: @dsolimano For me it was more, there's *no way* you are asking how to get `i`, so what are you *actually* asking?

Comment: Haha I am actually asking how to get i. Sorry guys, brain is tired. Should probably take a nap and start seriously questioning my programming abilities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void AllocatePosition(List<DbConnect.BidList> createBidList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < createBidList.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Position: " + i + " Item: " + createBidList[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

The `i` variable contains the position. Often `i` is used in for loops, and traditionally it stands for "index".

Answer (score 0):

Look at

```
for (int i = 0; i < createBidList.Count; i++)
```

`i` is the position of the item in the list, unless I'm missing something.  So you want

```
for (int i = 0; i < createBidList.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()); // show position of item (i.e. is it first, second, third...on the list
}
```